# Software Installer package with database integration issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation-package

Recently by using Visual Studio 2013 I have developed a program that displays alarm information based on its time and alarm tone settings. Those settings and files are stored in MySQL database.

The issue is:

> > Is there any way to install this application to another computer **without requiring to export the database**, **install MySQL database** and **configuring it**.

Just I want to Install the required database file and application **at ones including to the Software installation package**. or what you will advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Installshield Lite packaged with VS2013 you can create a setup that will include the setup of applications such as MySQL.

When the setup runs, it will install MySQL with the parameters provided.  If you configure the application to use silent install as discussed here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html then the installation will be seen as 'part of' your setup.

For the settings, I would recommend creating a setup application (console app) that will read a .sql file etc and configure the database.  This too can be run as a pre-requisite of your installation.

You can also do this all manually (i.e. write your own setup application that will call MySQL setup using Process class, install MySQL, create project folder, create shortcuts etc).  The Installshield is not fully functional and a gets a lot of bad press, but will do the job for a quick/simple install.